# Help Using Devise with the built-in Omniauth Support

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, oauth, devise, omniauth

I tried to follow https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/OmniAuth:-Overview, but somehow when I look at the generated routes I only see the callback path, and not the authorization path (and indeed I get the error on the view with the user_omniauth_authorize_path link).

I assume it might be a versions issue of OmniAuth and Devise ([since after 0.2.0.beta Omniath allows configurable setting, and the routes must be defined](https://github.com/intridea/omniauth/issues/closed#issue/201)). However, when trying to use an older OmniAuth version I get the error "`You are using an old OmniAuth version, please ensure 0.2.0.beta or later installed.`".

I tried working with Devise's master, 1.2.rc and the the omniauth branch and with both the entire omniauth gem (after 0.2.0.beta) and with 'oa-oauth' but without success.
I also tried to define the route:

```
match '/users/auth/:action/', :to => 'users/omniauth_callbacks#action', :as => 'user_omniauth_authorize'
```

This helped with the route, but when pressing the link I did get the error that devise cannot find a mapping. Funny enough, changing the controller in the devise_for to be invalid (like adding '/' before the users/omniauth_callbacks) resulted in an error the first time ("Controller name should not start with a slash"), but a small reload actually sent me to facebook and back (but  naturally the callback route was not defined).

I am new to Ruby, and not quite sure where I go from here. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: did you ever figure this problem out?

Comment: Nevermind, a simple server restart fixed it for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was due to different versions of omniauth and devise. What finally worked was using this configuration in my gemfile:

```
gem 'devise', :git => 'git://github.com/plataformatec/devise.git'
gem 'omniauth', '>=0.2.0.beta'
gem 'oa-oauth', :require => 'omniauth/oauth'
```

you can see more details about my implementation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7768356/add-friends-from-facebook-with-rails-3-omniauth-fbgraph).

Comment: looks like a problem in devise 1.4.8; omniauth 0.3.0 and devise 1.4.7 worked for me.

Comment: Place devise :omniauthable on the user model.This will solve the problem

Comment: @JudeArasu - it is already there (look at the implementation link) - still didn't work.

Answer (score 6):

This method is [defined by devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/omniauth/url_helpers.rb), not through routes.  Therefore it will not show up when you run `rake routes`.  The method takes one of the oauth providers that you have configured in config/initializers/devies.rb. For example if you define the following in devise.rb:

```
config.omniauth :facebook, FACEBOOK_APP_ID, FACEBOOK_APP_SECRET
```

Then you should build the authorize link like this:

```
<%= link_to "Facebook Sign in", user_omniauth_authorize_path(:facebook) %>
```

Comment: As I mentioned - this link doesn't work (undefined method) in my view.

Comment: My bad, I didn't click though on the 0.2 beta issue.  What provider are you using, I just upgraded to oa-oauth 0.2.0.beta5 with devise 1.2rc and facebook works fine for me.

Comment: devise 1.4.5 and omniauth 0.3.0.rc3 work fine. Be sure to restart the server -- it will never show up in rake routes.